# How can I convert scroll animation from HTML file to Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have this HTML and I want to convert it into a Vue template. Everything is fine and can be converted except the script links. I don't have any idea on how or where to add them. Can someone help me please?

```html
 <div class="row  sixthRow" data-aos="fade-up">
            <h3> How it works?</h3>
           
            <div class="col">
                <p class="steps  " ><svg id="Layer_1" enable-background="new 0 0 511.999 511.999" height="512" viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><g><path d="m415.475 444.61c-.768-5.827-2.049-10.644-3.918-14.723-.022-.051-.046-.101-.07-.15-2.238-4.68-4.782-7.96-8.008-10.325-3.619-2.652-7.733-3.997-12.23-3.997h-69.938v-393.683c0-4.236-1.086-8.013-3.225-11.218-2.378-3.568-6.148-6.071-11.524-7.648-3.721-1.125-8.83-1.887-15.613-2.329-5.681-.371-13.04-.537-23.861-.537-7.996 0-14.313 0-19.345.132-5.267.138-9.604.426-12.839.848-3.715.464-6.789 1.113-9.399 1.982-.067.022-.134.046-.201.069-2.763.986-5.081 2.2-7.066 3.701l-104.597 67.718c-.094.061-.186.123-.277.187-3.656 2.544-6.378 4.602-8.581 6.942-2.908 2.947-5.049 6.468-6.366 10.471-1.321 3.563-2.152 7.788-2.47 12.565-.271 4.083-.409 9.338-.409 15.62 0 10.16.414 17.93 1.266 23.754 1.073 7.327 3.319 12.723 6.867 16.492.07.074.141.147.212.22 4.391 4.389 10.178 6.123 17.204 5.154.131-.018.261-.039.391-.062 4.389-.784 9.82-2.739 16.604-5.978.177-.084.351-.174.522-.269l63.688-35.138.003 97.033c0 5.523 4.478 10 10 10s10-4.478 10-10l-.003-113.972c0-3.538-1.87-6.813-4.916-8.611-3.048-1.799-6.818-1.854-9.915-.145l-78.256 43.176c-5.922 2.811-9.253 3.827-11.043 4.176-.11.014-.21.023-.301.03-.35-.77-.87-2.281-1.269-5.004-.7-4.787-1.055-11.805-1.055-20.858 0-5.842.123-10.65.365-14.291.241-3.623.841-5.825 1.301-7.034.066-.173.127-.349.184-.525.364-1.144.878-2.006 1.667-2.794.088-.088.174-.178.258-.269 1.039-1.119 3.169-2.663 5.339-4.176l104.807-67.854c.279-.181.548-.375.807-.582.176-.141.623-.429 1.659-.807 1.321-.429 3.158-.791 5.512-1.086 2.606-.34 6.251-.573 10.83-.693 4.77-.122 10.971-.122 18.822-.122 10.369 0 17.326.152 22.558.494 6.808.444 9.906 1.145 11.146 1.521.038.012.075.022.113.034.147.043.282.084.405.124v403.241c0 5.522 4.478 10 10 10h79.938c.14 0 .216.012.226.014.016.007.079.039.179.113.027.02.676.512 1.755 2.749.995 2.2 1.748 5.203 2.233 8.896.553 4.311.821 9.883.821 17.036 0 6.495-.35 12-1.038 16.362-.809 5.122-1.691 7.623-2.289 8.818-.08.16-.156.323-.228.487-.622 1.428-1.171 1.95-1.164 1.953-.04.028-.079.055-.119.084-.076.055-.1.071-.246.071h-270.123c-.029-.018-.064-.041-.106-.07-.133-.144-.672-.775-1.433-2.366-.025-.052-.05-.104-.076-.155-.599-1.198-1.482-3.701-2.291-8.823-.689-4.363-1.039-9.867-1.039-16.361 0-7.151.269-12.724.818-17.003.49-3.726 1.243-6.729 2.237-8.929.924-1.915 1.584-2.658 1.809-2.876h91.118c5.523 0 10-4.478 10-10v-113.971c0-5.522-4.477-10-10-10s-10 4.478-10 10v103.972h-81.283c-4.617 0-8.848 1.489-12.249 4.31-2.926 2.341-5.372 5.618-7.474 10.014-.023.05-.047.099-.07.149-1.869 4.079-3.15 8.896-3.921 14.755-.671 5.235-.984 11.457-.984 19.58 0 7.642.42 14.015 1.283 19.481.99 6.266 2.298 10.896 4.115 14.563 2.18 4.535 4.756 7.801 7.873 9.978 3.464 2.457 7.414 3.755 11.428 3.755h270.369c4.266 0 8.349-1.298 11.813-3.755 3.271-2.284 6.015-5.784 7.951-10.139 1.776-3.639 3.062-8.226 4.037-14.401.862-5.467 1.282-11.839 1.282-19.481 0-8.125-.313-14.347-.987-19.614z"/><path d="m212.299 276.443c5.523 0 10-4.478 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10h-.007c-5.523 0-9.996 4.478-9.996 10s4.48 10 10.003 10z"/></g></g></svg></p>
                <p data-aos="fade-up">Post Your Question</p>
            </div>


            <div class="col line circle  mb-5" color="green" >
            
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                
                <p class="steps " ><svg id="Layer_1" enable-background="new 0 0 511.999 511.999" height="512" viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><g><path d="m426.956 442.363c-.976-6.497-2.317-11.316-4.223-15.153-2.315-4.801-5.178-8.304-8.741-10.694-3.688-2.679-8.041-4.093-12.611-4.093h-166.76l39.823-40.722c28.535-28.282 51.806-53.511 69.164-74.983 17.513-21.663 31.329-41.787 41.079-59.84 10.024-18.693 16.481-35.7 19.752-52.054 3.083-15.946 4.646-32.16 4.646-48.19 0-19.114-3.323-37.252-9.877-53.906-6.681-16.981-16.903-31.799-30.383-44.041-13.361-12.133-30.329-21.752-50.452-28.596-19.817-6.696-43.12-10.091-69.26-10.091-16.317 0-32.424 1.566-47.937 4.67-14.967 3.097-29.01 6.953-41.737 11.462-12.877 4.561-23.479 9.212-32.369 14.196-8.951 4.957-15.212 9.124-19.141 12.737-.103.095-.203.19-.302.289-3.63 3.631-6.218 6.712-7.912 9.422-.048.076-.094.152-.14.23-1.818 3.09-3.173 6.526-4.027 10.217-.962 3.713-1.623 7.464-2.024 11.488-.386 3.981-.558 8.762-.558 15.502 0 9.256.312 16.618.948 22.482.606 5.7 1.479 10.778 2.667 15.525.035.138.072.275.112.411 1.641 5.541 3.84 9.376 6.91 12.045 3.481 3.146 7.798 4.809 12.498 4.809 5.432 0 11.469-2.41 18.994-7.584 5.369-3.575 12.149-7.584 20.68-12.226 8.183-4.396 17.673-8.366 28.208-11.799 10.422-3.396 22.509-5.119 35.925-5.119 9.215 0 17.147 1.304 23.498 3.844 6.544 2.682 11.688 6.097 15.728 10.438 4.269 4.59 7.462 9.849 9.523 15.722 2.228 6.154 3.357 12.861 3.357 19.935 0 8.448-.996 17.3-2.959 26.31-2.043 9.371-5.731 19.606-10.964 30.421-2.405 4.972-.325 10.952 4.646 13.357 4.967 2.402 10.951.326 13.357-4.646 5.917-12.23 10.123-23.964 12.501-34.873 2.269-10.406 3.418-20.691 3.418-30.568 0-9.401-1.531-18.398-4.519-26.649-2.946-8.396-7.562-16.008-13.719-22.629-6.054-6.507-13.507-11.519-22.864-15.354-8.804-3.521-19.234-5.306-31.005-5.306-15.524 0-29.696 2.054-42.121 6.104-11.661 3.8-22.251 8.239-31.524 13.222-9.139 4.973-16.438 9.296-22.318 13.216-.042.028-.084.057-.126.085-3.79 2.611-6.043 3.569-7.099 3.915-.199-.429-.476-1.112-.79-2.149-.934-3.778-1.63-7.893-2.13-12.593-.562-5.162-.834-11.816-.834-20.344 0-5.99.147-10.304.461-13.545.3-3.003.794-5.797 1.511-8.541.026-.104.052-.206.075-.31.379-1.664.976-3.232 1.729-4.548.529-.819 1.83-2.562 4.866-5.612 1.624-1.461 5.684-4.591 15.196-9.859 7.931-4.446 17.519-8.638 29.311-12.814 11.874-4.206 25.033-7.815 39.049-10.716 14.162-2.833 28.948-4.27 43.951-4.27 23.959 0 45.107 3.041 62.839 9.032 17.495 5.95 32.106 14.18 43.428 24.46 11.344 10.303 19.592 22.261 25.217 36.559 5.633 14.313 8.488 29.985 8.488 46.583 0 14.76-1.44 29.696-4.27 44.332-2.866 14.33-8.674 29.528-17.739 46.434-9.152 16.945-22.281 36.037-39.021 56.745-16.911 20.918-39.703 45.615-67.745 73.406-.037.036-.074.073-.11.11l-56.495 57.77c-2.813 2.878-3.629 7.161-2.068 10.87 1.562 3.71 5.193 6.122 9.218 6.122h190.526c.387 0 .577.063.885.295.185.138.374.27.567.395.081.053.827.581 1.903 2.821.023.048.047.096.07.143.931 1.861 1.729 4.976 2.37 9.256.688 4.583 1.037 10.176 1.037 16.624 0 7.305-.267 12.989-.815 17.379-.472 3.774-1.229 7.214-2.25 10.227-.556 1.331-1.077 2.022-1.313 2.261-.169.087-.442.177-.925.177h-278.136c-4.617 0-8.539-.408-11.656-1.212-2.036-.525-3.591-1.397-4.646-2.618-1.372-1.579-2.464-4.266-3.242-7.983-.959-4.584-1.445-11.061-1.445-19.25 0-7.774.358-14.462 1.063-19.877.681-5.224 1.762-9.449 3.304-12.918 1.764-3.97 4.012-7.9 6.651-11.639 3.035-4.252 6.72-8.583 11.263-13.24.048-.049.095-.099.142-.149l83.75-89.486c4.264-4.459 8.338-8.829 12.11-12.991 3.709-4.092 3.398-10.416-.693-14.125-4.09-3.708-10.415-3.4-14.125.693-3.664 4.042-7.63 8.295-11.785 12.641-.024.025-.049.052-.073.078l-83.718 89.451c-5.229 5.367-9.529 10.44-13.179 15.551-3.425 4.852-6.325 9.931-8.619 15.094-2.336 5.255-3.926 11.292-4.859 18.456-.829 6.357-1.231 13.704-1.231 22.462 0 9.697.611 17.334 1.869 23.348 1.509 7.201 4.035 12.765 7.704 16.983 3.69 4.273 8.795 7.346 14.763 8.886 4.749 1.226 10.353 1.847 16.653 1.847h278.137c4.515 0 8.812-1.314 12.426-3.801.083-.057.164-.115.245-.174 3.495-2.563 6.261-6.344 8.219-11.238.058-.146.112-.293.164-.44 1.519-4.385 2.622-9.273 3.279-14.53.652-5.221.97-11.717.97-19.859-.001-7.443-.424-14.035-1.259-19.598z"/><path d="m253.119 259.061c0-5.522-4.478-10-10-10h-.008c-5.522 0-9.996 4.478-9.996 10s4.481 10 10.004 10 10-4.478 10-10z"/></g></g></svg></p>
                
                <p data-aos="fade-up">Select Solver </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col line circle mb-5"  color="green" >
            
            </div>
          
            <div class="col" >
                <p class="steps "><svg id="Layer_1" enable-background="new 0 0 511.999 511.999" height="512" viewBox="0 0 511.999 511.999" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><g><path d="m416.64 311.263c-5.305-13.463-13.065-25.707-23.066-36.393-9.952-10.634-22.244-19.545-36.5-26.469-5.129-2.517-10.455-4.705-16.019-6.577 3.122-1.638 6.131-3.393 9.022-5.264 11.843-7.663 21.688-16.959 29.264-27.629 7.782-10.663 13.725-22.954 17.655-36.509 3.929-13.41 5.921-27.939 5.921-43.185 0-19.848-3.427-38.066-10.168-54.114-6.693-16.116-16.87-30.011-30.284-41.329-13.139-10.972-29.374-19.453-48.273-25.217-18.798-5.691-40.317-8.577-63.96-8.577-18.213 0-35.367 1.584-51.064 4.723-16.195 3.375-29.733 7.17-41.422 11.616-11.906 4.579-22.062 9.399-30.246 14.363-8.909 5.494-13.742 8.874-16.684 11.667-.063.06-.125.12-.186.182-3.479 3.48-5.569 6.077-6.963 8.656-1.409 2.526-2.556 5.415-3.604 9.079-.012.04-.022.08-.034.12-.94 3.452-1.541 7.431-1.837 12.181-.266 4.373-.395 9.575-.395 15.902 0 7.783.264 14.073.81 19.253.556 5.148 1.443 9.486 2.637 12.893.048.135.098.27.151.402 1.792 4.484 4.428 7.795 7.837 9.841 2.904 1.804 6.343 2.718 10.225 2.718 5.004 0 10.705-2.212 19.062-7.394 6.234-3.864 13.635-8.034 21.997-12.395 8.484-4.299 18.176-8.275 28.902-11.852 10.202-3.515 20.867-5.223 32.603-5.223 10.127 0 18.806 1.343 25.798 3.991.041.016.083.031.124.046 3.203 1.165 6.182 2.568 8.854 4.172 4.737 2.843 10.878 1.305 13.72-3.431 2.841-4.736 1.306-10.879-3.431-13.72-3.749-2.249-7.869-4.198-12.248-5.795-9.378-3.542-20.114-5.264-32.817-5.264-13.794 0-26.955 2.124-39.021 6.28-11.584 3.862-22.208 8.229-31.578 12.981-.033.018-.065.034-.099.051-8.821 4.598-16.674 9.024-23.343 13.158-4.57 2.834-6.974 3.85-8.058 4.211-.405-1.326-.993-3.78-1.427-7.794-.463-4.39-.697-10.153-.697-17.132 0-5.919.117-10.725.356-14.675.205-3.283.594-6.006 1.156-8.092.598-2.079 1.217-3.695 1.841-4.804.037-.065.073-.132.109-.199.136-.255.781-1.286 3.409-3.925 1.804-1.677 6.285-4.727 13.265-9.031 7.107-4.312 16.188-8.604 26.956-12.744 10.658-4.055 23.204-7.561 38.277-10.701 14.332-2.862 30.166-4.315 47.065-4.315 21.678 0 41.246 2.598 58.145 7.715 16.31 4.973 30.194 12.184 41.23 21.398 10.913 9.209 19.214 20.541 24.688 33.72 5.803 13.812 8.623 28.99 8.623 46.405 0 13.341-1.721 25.979-5.122 37.588-3.294 11.358-8.22 21.573-14.643 30.361-.028.039-.057.078-.085.117-6.192 8.736-13.996 16.084-23.855 22.465-9.663 6.252-21.033 10.997-33.793 14.101-4.482 1.091-7.637 5.104-7.637 9.717v1.128c0 5.061 3.781 9.324 8.806 9.929 15.869 1.908 29.501 5.74 41.712 11.73 12.079 5.867 22.398 13.323 30.671 22.163 8.388 8.961 14.623 18.793 19.074 30.089 4.438 11.154 6.688 23.283 6.688 36.05 0 22.08-4.209 41.812-12.485 58.595-8.513 17.025-20.292 31.385-35.01 42.68-15.196 11.662-33.576 20.676-54.563 26.773-21.724 6.154-45.653 9.275-71.125 9.275-15.677 0-30.437-1.136-43.856-3.372-14.091-2.369-25.935-5.128-36.209-8.435-.033-.011-.066-.021-.1-.031-9.876-3.064-18.376-6.456-25.321-10.111-6.589-3.412-10.487-5.887-11.998-7.108-1.125-1.02-1.863-1.975-2.371-3.065-.875-2.099-1.7-4.555-2.367-7.029-.729-2.81-1.263-6.435-1.59-10.794-.322-4.193-.473-9.688-.473-17.289 0-13.598 1.415-18.728 2.072-20.373.085-.186.164-.343.237-.476 1.151.385 3.434 1.301 7.378 3.438 6.313 3.42 14.372 7.123 23.95 11.006 9.637 3.907 21.065 7.589 33.966 10.942 13.3 3.459 28.489 5.213 45.146 5.213 14.248 0 27.21-1.749 38.524-5.199 11.225-3.422 21.164-8.454 29.544-14.955.051-.039.101-.079.15-.119 8.386-6.767 14.787-15.018 19.027-24.521.018-.039.034-.078.052-.118 4.035-9.367 6.081-19.853 6.081-31.164 0-12.427-2.489-23.853-7.399-33.96-.017-.033-.033-.067-.051-.102-5.187-10.377-12.66-19.136-22.212-26.034-9.302-6.927-21.196-12.319-35.329-16.023-13.719-3.632-29.851-5.474-47.947-5.474h-41.125c-1.83 0-3.25-.158-4.229-.47-.108-.111-.331-.374-.618-.89-.442-.867-1.446-3.232-2.04-7.75-.533-4.053-.793-9.654-.793-17.126 0-7.01.256-12.261.783-16.053.633-4.56 1.506-6.336 1.758-6.772.103-.176.199-.355.29-.537.151-.304.28-.484.354-.577.77-.354 1.889-.541 3.24-.541h41.376c15.214 0 28.843-1.832 40.512-5.444 12.026-3.561 22.502-8.941 31.202-16.047 7.288-6.053 13.177-13.274 17.5-21.462 2.579-4.884.711-10.934-4.173-13.513-4.886-2.578-10.935-.71-13.513 4.173-3.138 5.941-7.257 10.984-12.529 15.363-6.674 5.45-14.595 9.48-24.218 12.324-.044.013-.088.025-.132.039-9.761 3.03-21.419 4.566-34.649 4.566h-41.376c-4.304 0-8.227.808-11.663 2.401-4.075 1.82-7.416 5.1-9.684 9.502-1.961 3.495-3.305 8.005-4.106 13.772-.663 4.779-.973 10.755-.973 18.805 0 8.469.306 14.74.963 19.735.758 5.758 2.169 10.635 4.192 14.497.025.048.051.096.077.144 2.544 4.667 6.171 8.074 10.489 9.853.061.024.121.049.183.072 3.392 1.32 7.134 1.935 11.775 1.935h41.125c16.37 0 30.779 1.617 42.853 4.814 11.689 3.063 21.287 7.356 28.526 12.759.045.034.09.067.136.1 7.016 5.055 12.269 11.188 16.059 18.749 3.61 7.452 5.365 15.686 5.365 25.171 0 8.551-1.489 16.354-4.425 23.194-2.968 6.627-7.293 12.185-13.221 16.984-6.437 4.978-14.188 8.869-23.041 11.568-9.424 2.873-20.423 4.33-32.692 4.33-14.96 0-28.456-1.537-40.114-4.569-12.06-3.135-22.651-6.54-31.483-10.121-8.895-3.604-16.275-6.988-21.938-10.057-7.783-4.217-13.158-6.097-17.428-6.097-7.874 0-14.449 4.632-18.04 12.707-.032.071-.063.145-.094.217-2.458 5.899-3.652 15.114-3.652 28.17 0 8.126.169 14.106.53 18.804.42 5.605 1.131 10.283 2.196 14.391.948 3.521 2.066 6.819 3.323 9.806.031.074.064.149.098.224 1.693 3.764 4.145 7.04 7.491 10.016.079.07.159.139.239.206 3.063 2.553 8.353 5.783 15.664 9.57 7.958 4.188 17.582 8.047 28.604 11.469 11.19 3.598 23.937 6.575 38.979 9.104 14.518 2.42 30.384 3.646 47.159 3.646 27.315 0 53.079-3.376 76.641-10.051 23.448-6.813 44.047-16.949 61.224-30.131 17.143-13.155 30.843-29.844 40.747-49.651 9.67-19.608 14.572-42.315 14.572-67.49.003-15.312-2.725-29.928-8.091-43.414z"/><path d="m296.604 134.013c0-5.522-4.478-10-10-10h-.008c-5.522 0-9.996 4.478-9.996 10s4.481 10 10.004 10 10-4.478 10-10z"/></g></g></svg></p>
                <p >  Proceed To Payment</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col line mb-5 circle" color="green" >
             
            </div>
            <div class="col" >
                <p class="steps  "><svg id="Layer_1" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><g><path d="m283.376 85.599h-.771c-3.586 0-6.897 1.92-8.679 5.032l-41.648 72.76c-2.744 4.793-1.082 10.903 3.711 13.646 4.793 2.746 10.903 1.083 13.646-3.711l23.741-41.476v177.385h-101.537l33.079-57.788c2.744-4.793 1.083-10.903-3.711-13.646-4.792-2.745-10.903-1.082-13.646 3.711l-41.646 72.756c-1.771 3.095-1.761 6.898.028 9.983s5.085 4.984 8.651 4.984h128.784c5.523 0 10-4.478 10-10v-223.636c-.002-5.523-4.479-10-10.002-10z"/><path d="m441.524 324.25c-5.714-12.407-13.668-15.015-19.339-15.015h-33.185v-283.041c0-3.974-1.264-9.774-7.285-14.846-.144-.122-.292-.239-.442-.353-3.891-2.917-9.114-5.176-15.527-6.714-6.023-1.565-13.735-2.664-23.563-3.357-8.727-.621-19.722-.924-33.616-.924-11.966 0-22.294.266-30.698.791-9.208.575-16.417 1.44-22.036 2.645-6.695 1.435-11.403 3.006-15.264 5.098-.053.028-.105.058-.158.087-4.557 2.576-7.963 5.745-10.125 9.42-.027.046-.054.092-.08.139l-151.276 266.82c-.033.059-.066.117-.098.176-2.59 4.791-4.879 9.698-6.805 14.586-.044.111-.085.223-.125.336-1.838 5.206-3.187 10.144-4.124 15.094-.967 5.108-1.667 10.92-2.081 17.273-.37 5.675-.535 12.337-.535 21.602 0 10.89.444 18.883 1.399 25.153 1.067 7.013 2.793 12.575 5.275 17.007.078.139.16.276.244.411 3.238 5.183 7.424 8.629 12.442 10.246 3.568 1.182 7.77 1.781 12.49 1.781h176.364v78.298c0 4.661 1.343 8.855 3.992 12.468 2.588 3.529 6.605 6.23 12.282 8.26.102.036.204.07.307.104 4.527 1.454 10.337 2.579 16.804 3.253 6.244.65 13.843.953 23.914.953 10.553 0 18.322-.304 24.45-.955 6.118-.651 11.701-1.726 16.595-3.192.131-.04.261-.081.39-.126 5.808-2.004 9.903-4.661 12.509-8.115 2.868-3.653 4.382-8.022 4.382-12.648v-78.298h33.185c5.1 0 14.469-2.127 19.973-16.361 3.149-7.846 4.68-18.631 4.68-32.968-.002-16.317-1.69-27.47-5.315-35.088zm-17.944 60.646c-.021.051-.041.103-.061.154-.837 2.177-1.565 3.197-1.929 3.615h-42.59c-5.523 0-10 4.478-10 10v88.298c0 .088-.007.137-.007.14-.006.015-.039.074-.115.169-.021.026-.043.054-.064.08-.243.177-1.067.707-3.041 1.403-3.669 1.083-7.962 1.891-12.765 2.401-5.334.568-12.64.844-22.334.844-9.234 0-16.378-.276-21.841-.846-4.96-.517-9.426-1.351-12.604-2.353-1.737-.633-2.521-1.125-2.799-1.326-.029-.09-.053-.238-.053-.513v-88.298c0-5.522-4.477-10-10-10h-186.365c-3.226 0-5.162-.42-6.218-.772-.044-.015-.088-.029-.133-.043-.2-.063-.755-.482-1.49-1.607-.862-1.614-2.015-4.632-2.837-10.032-.788-5.178-1.171-12.421-1.171-22.144 0-8.694.157-15.145.493-20.3.361-5.546.958-10.544 1.774-14.856.736-3.889 1.807-7.812 3.272-11.986 1.607-4.06 3.517-8.146 5.678-12.151l151.162-266.62c.113-.175.701-.973 2.629-2.075 2.061-1.098 5.284-2.107 9.853-3.086 4.64-.995 10.884-1.728 19.091-2.24 7.991-.499 17.9-.752 29.452-.752 13.414 0 23.944.286 32.199.875 8.525.601 15.261 1.537 20.021 2.783.072.02.145.037.217.055 4.639 1.104 7.009 2.417 7.996 3.09v292.433c0 5.522 4.477 10 10 10h42.321c.399.441 1.143 1.431 2.056 3.421.023.052.048.104.072.154 1.545 3.226 3.388 10.446 3.388 26.525 0 11.607-1.096 20.207-3.257 25.56z"/><path d="m218.599 217.417c5.523 0 10-4.478 10-10s-4.477-10-10-10h-.007c-5.523 0-9.996 4.478-9.996 10s4.48 10 10.003 10z"/></g></g></svg></p>
                <p> Receive Answer</p>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js" ></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/scripts.js" ></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
```

Comment: What is `./assets/js/scripts.js`?

Answer (score 1):

`<script>` tags for third party scripts usually go into `index.html` (`public/index.html` in a Vue CLI scaffolded project):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js" ></script>

<script>
AOS.init();
</script>
```